# How to redirect from http to https?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible to configure webpack-dev-server for https and redirect incoming http requests to https? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: why not do it in server.js.middleware ?         if(env === 'production'){
      if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
          return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
      }
      return next();
    }
    next();

Comment: It's a React-based web app which is accessing a backend based on Kotlin/Java... I want to have some production-like tests using http://